# How to make a single MySQL query that uses the results of another query

Tags: mysql

I have a Perl program that queries a MySQL database to bring back results based upon which "report" option a user has selected from a web page.

One of the reports is all occupants of a student housing building who have applied for a parking permit, but who have not yet been given one.

When the students apply for a permit, it records the specifics about their car (make, model, year, color, etc.) in a single table row.  Each apartment can have up to three students, and each student may apply for a permit.  So an apartment might have 0 permits, or 1, 2, or 3 permits, depending upon how many of them have cars.

What I'd like to be able to do, is execute a MySQL query that will find out how many occupants in each apartment have applied for a parking permit, and then based on the results of that query, find out how many permits have been issued.  If the number of permits issued is less than the number of applications, that apartment number should be returned in the result set.  It doesn't have to name the specific occupant, just the fact that the apartment has at least one occupant who has applied for a permit, but not yet received one.

So I have two tables, one is called `occupant_info` and it contains all kinds of info about the occupant, but the relevant fields are:

```
counter (a unique row id)
parking_permit_1_number
parking_permit_2_number
parking_permit_3_number
```

When a parking permit has been assigned, it is recorded in the appropriate `parking_permit_#_number field` (if it's occupant number one's permit, it would be recorded in `parking_permit_1_number`, etc.).

The second table is called, `parking_permits`, and contains all of the car/owner specifics (make, model, year, owner, owner address, etc.).  It also contains a field which references the counter from the `occupant_info` table.

So an example would be:

*occupant_info table*

```
counter | parking_permit_1_number | parking_permit_2_number | parking_permit_3_number
--------|-------------------------|-------------------------|------------------------
1       | 12345                   |                         | 98765
2       | 43920                   |                         |  
3       | 30239                   |                         | 34233
```

*parking_permits table*

```
counter | counter_from_occupant_info | permit_1_name | permit_2_name   | permit_3_name
--------|----------------------------|---------------|-----------------|-------------------
1       |2                           | David Jones   | James Cameron   | Michael Smerconish
2       |3                           | Bill Epps     | Hillary Clinton | Donald Trump
3       |1                           | Joanne Miller |                 | Sridevi Gupta
```

I want a query that will first look at how many occupants in an apartment have applied for a permit.  This is determined by counting the names in the `parking_permits` table.  In that table, row 1 has three names, row 2 has three names, and row 3 has two names.  The query should then look at the `occupant_info` table, and for each `counter_from_occupant_info` from the `parking_permits` table, see if the same number of parking permits have been issued.  This can be determined by comparing the number of non-blank `parking_permit_#_number` fields.

Using the data above, the query would see the following :

*parking_permit table row 1*

```
Has counter_from_occupant_info equal to "2"
Has three names
The row in occupant_info with counter = "2" has only one permit number issued,
    so counter_from_occupant_info 2 from parking_permits should be in the result set.
```

*parking_permit table row 2*

```
Has counter_from_occupant_info equal to "3"
Has three names
The row in occupant_info with counter = "3" has only two permit numbers issued,
    so counter_from_occupant_info 3 from parking_permits should be in the result set.
```

*parking_permit table row 3*

```
Has counter_from_occupant_info equal to "1"
Has two names
The row in occupant_info with counter = "1" has two permit numbers issued,
    so this row should *not* be in the result set.
```

I've thought about using `if`, `then`, `case`, `when`, `type logic` to do this in one query, but frankly can't wrap my head around how to do so.

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( SELECT counter_from_occupant_info
            FROM parking_permits
            WHERE parking_permit_1_name != ""
              AND parking_permit_2_name != ""
              AND parking_permit_3_name != "" ) THEN 
IF ( SELECT parking_permit_1_number,
            parking_permit_2_number,
            parking_permit_3_number
     FROM occupant_info
     WHERE counter = ***somehow reference counter from above case statement--I don't know how to do this***
```

But then my head explodes and I realize I don't know what the heck I'm doing.

Any help would be appreciated.  :-)

```
    Doug
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too long that anyone would read that. Reduce it to the core problem please.

Comment: To answer the title's question: subqueries

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems:

1. Your occupants table schema is bad. There's worse out there, but it looks like someone that doesn't understand how a database works built this table.
2. Your permits table is also bad. Same reason.
3. You have no idea what you are doing (kidding... kidding...)

**Problem 1:**

Your occupants table should probably be two tables. Because an occupant could have 0-3 permits (possibly more, I can't tell from the sample data) then you need a table for your occupant's attributes (name, height, gender, age, primary smell, favorite color, first rent date, I dunno).

*Occupants*

```
OccupantID | favorite TV Show | number of limbs | first name | last name | aptBuilding
```

And... another table for Relationship between the occupant and the permit:

*Occupant_permits*

```
OccupantID | Permit ID | status
```

Now... an occupant can have as many permits as you can stuff into that table and the relationship between them has a status "Applied for", or "Granted" or "Revoked" or what have you.

**Problem 2**

Your permit info table is doing double duty as well. It holds the information about a permit (it's name) as well as the relationship to the occupant. Since we already have a relationship to the occupant with the "Occupant_Permits" table above, we just need a permits table to hold attributes of a permit:

*Permits*

```
 Permit ID | Permit Name | Description | etc..
```

*Problem 3*

Now that you have a correct schema where objects are in their own table (Occupant, Permit, Occupant and Permit Relationship) your query to get a list of apartments that have at least one occupant that has applied, but not yet received a permit would be:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.AptBuilding)
FROM 
    occupants as o
    INNER JOIN occupants_permit as op 
        ON o.occupant_id = op.occupant_id
    INNER JOIN permits as p 
        ON op.permit_id = p.permit_id
WHERE
    op.Status = "Applied"
```

That's nice and simple and you aren't relying on `CASE` or `UNION` or count comparison or any fancy stuff. Just nice straight joins and a simple WHERE clause. This will be fast to query and there's no funny business.

---

Because your schema isn't great, in order to get something similar you'll need to make use of either UNION queries to stack your many permit_N_ fields into a single field and run something similar to the above query, or you'll have use a fair amount of CASE/IF statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pCounter
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            counter as Ocounter
            CASE WHEN parking_permit_1_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            +
            CASE WHEN parking_permit_2_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            +
            CASE WHEN parking_permit_3_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS permitCount
        FROM occupant_info
    ) as o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            counter_from_occupant_info as pCounter
            CASE WHEN parking_permit_1_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            +
            CASE WHEN parking_permit_2_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            +
            CASE WHEN parking_permit_3_Name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS permitPermitCount
    ) as p ON o.Ocounter = p.Pcounter

WHERE p.permitCounter > o.PermitCount
```

I'm not 100% convinced that is exactly what you are looking for since your schema is confusing where you have multiple objects in a single table and everything is pivoted, but... it should get you in the ball park.

This will be much slower too. There's intermediate result sets, CASE statements, and math, so don't expect MySQL to spit this out in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, very much, JNevill.  Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of time in which to rewrite the (very large) codebase that is built on this database structure, so the lousy table layouts will have to stay for now.  The query you wrote at the end of your comment seems in line with what I need.  I'm trying to tweak it for my purposes now.  Your help is *greatly* appreciated!